# How to assign more RAM to Colab session?

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, ram

I tried searching the same question but most of the answers I have seen were talking about upgrading to Colab Pro especially when Colab crashes due to the limited RAM size.

 My question is how to assign more RAM to each session when running multiple sessions at the same time given that I have enough RAM but colab is not fully using all the RAM resources.
For example, I am running 5 different sessions simultaneously and I have around 51GB RAM since I subscribe Colab Pro. I was simply guessing each session may use max RAM (e.g. 10GB) or at least more than what it uses now (e.g. 2.28GB) if a task takes a lot of time but each session only uses 2.28GB.
I want to speed up the process of these tasks. In that case, what should I do? If allocating more RAM to each session works, how can I do it?
Thank you.

[image]

[image]